# HTML input type number - How do I know "step" functionality triggered change event?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, textbox, onchange

I have a standard HTML input text box which triggers a javascript function on "onChange" event. The input has a step function enabled and the value changes by 0.005 on pressing up or down arrows. I want to determine if the "onChange" event is triggered by pressing arrow keys or by user entering a value in the input field. How do I distinguish between the two?

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.005" />
```

Comment: Listen for a keypress to check for arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <input id='myfun' type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.005" onchange="myFunction()" />
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        console.log('My new value : ', document.getElementById('myfun').value);

        var str = document.getElementById('myfun').value
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = str;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

## Check out my code and you would see every time you change the code, it shows the value and all you needs

```
<input id='myfun' type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.005" onchange="myFunction()" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

```
function myFunction(){
  console.log('My new value : ', document.getElementById('myfun').value);

  var str = document.getElementById('myfun').value
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = str;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <input id='myfun' type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.005" onchange="myFunction()" />
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      console.log('My new value : ', document.getElementById('myfun').value);

      var str = document.getElementById('myfun').value
      document.getElementById('result').innerText = str;
    }

  </script>

</html>
```